# Is there any way to get databases belong to particular user

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I am making script to backup users home directories and databases.
i can make backup by going through dirs but i am not able to find a way to gets databases belong to particular user

Comment: Databases don't belong to users in MySQL.

Comment: Are you talking about Linux users or MySQL users? Are you backing up in SQL format or hot-copying the database dirs?

Comment: Are the database usernames the same as the home directories?

Comment: yes db users same as home dirs and DB names start with username_something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use `mysqldump`, which doesn't support wildcards in database names AFAIK, you could first from your Python script issue a `SHOW DATABASES` query, which will return all database names.

Then group them by user name, and call `mysqldump` with the `--databases` option based on the result of your script.

There may be simpler, turnkey solutions however.